# Autentificar en angularJS con $scope?

Tags: angularjs

la duda me ha surgido porque mi login es algo distinto ya que al validar un usuario en el WS, este me tiene que retornar datos en JSON, ya que con esos datos yo consulto a otro WS para recibir nuevos datos y mostrarlos en la vista

estoy intentando con NG-cookies, es decir que si pasa la autentifacion me guarde los datos en una cookie:

```
cookieStore.put('nombreCookie',response);
```

cosa que al refrescar la pagina no se pierdan los datos ya que por miestras al iniciar session los datos se guardan en una variable llamada 
`logindata`. que es la que uso para hacer las peticiones pero como solo se carga al iniciar session no se guardan y provoca que a refrescar pagina ya no extstan datos...

quiero saber como puedo enviar como parametro los datos almacenados en la cookie...

saludos.

Comment: Pues conoces localStorage??

Comment: lei que la diferencia es que  su duración es  mientras la persona navega en la pagina, cuando la persona se sale se pierden los datos...

Comment: pues no se quien dijo eso, por que eso no es asi, los datos permanecen incluso dejando la pagina, se uso mucho para hacer los almacenamientos en aplicaciones hibridas, cuando no se usa algun plugin para usar el almacenamiento nativo.

Comment: gracias, lo investigare.

Answer (score 1):

Si tu aplicación va a consumir dos  o más WS yo recomendaria que usaras autenticacion por token JWT.

Si usas cookies debes tener cuidado al momento de crearlas por que tendras problemas si tus WS estan alojados en dominios diferentes por aquello del *Access-Control-Allow-Origin*.

aquí te dejo algo de información al respecto. 
[¿QUÉ ES LA AUTENTICACIÓN BASADA EN TOKEN?](https://carlosazaustre.es/blog/que-es-la-autenticacion-con-token/)

Tambien te recomiendo este modulo para angular, es muy sencillo y es facil integrar con diferentes sistemas de autenticacion oauth2
[Satellizer](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer)

Saludos.